# Can't make Replace method work with Array Formula (VBA)

Tags: vba, dynamic, static, array-formulas

I have looked for a solution to enter a long array formula, but replace method isn't working.
this is my code:

```
Sub code()
Dim parte1, parte2 As String
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RESUMEN E. CRITICOS")
    ''RUT
        parte1 = "IFERROR(INDEX(rut_cliente,SMALL(IF(plataforma=R1C2,ROW(rut_cliente)-ROW(BD_EV!R3C1)+1),ROWS(BD_EV!R2C1:R[-1]C[-2]))),"""")"
        With .Range("C3")
            .FormulaArray = "=IF(R1C2=""Todas"",IFERROR(INDEX(rut_cliente,SMALL(IF(plataforma<>""*"",ROW(rut_cliente)-ROW(BD_EV!R3C1)+1),ROWS(BD_EV!R2C1:R[-1]C[-2]))),""""),reemplazar)"
            .Replace "reemplazar", parte1, xlPart
        End With
End With
End Sub
```

This array formula brings a list of values from another sheet and works with named ranges, but also with static references. The problem is that if I want to delete rows on the referenced sheet, the static references will stop working. I tried using a workaround with named ranges for the static references but, that didn't help(they constantly re-arrange the referenced range... cant tell why). This is the static references are: `ROW(BD_EV!R3C1)+1)` and `ROWS(BD_EV!R2C1:R[-1]C[-2])`.
Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace `reeplazar` in your string and then all you have to do is make sure you assign it as an array formula when you assign it to a cell. I am trusting that your formula works as I can't test it.

But this code will do the replace for you

```
Sub code()
Dim parte1, parte2 As String
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RESUMEN E. CRITICOS")
    ''RUT

        parte1 = "IFERROR(INDEX(r‌​ut_cliente,SMALL(IF(‌​plataforma=R1C2,ROW(‌​rut_cliente)-ROW(BD_‌​EV!R3C1)+1),ROWS(BD_‌​EV!R2C1:R[-1]C[-2]))‌​),""""))"

        rep = "=IF(R1C2=""Todas"",IFERROR(INDEX(rut_cliente,SMALL(IF(plataforma<>""*"",ROW(rut_cliente)-ROW(BD_EV!R3C1)+1),ROWS(BD_EV!R2C1:R[-1]C[-2]))),""""),reemplazar)"
        arrayFormula = Replace(rep, "reemplazar", parte1)
        With .Range("C3")
            .FormulaArray = arrayFormula
        End With
End With
End Sub
```

Or if you wanted to get the value from the cell itself,

```
Sub code()
Dim parte1, parte2 As String
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RESUMEN E. CRITICOS")
    ''RUT

        parte1 = "IFERROR(INDEX(rut_cliente,SMALL(IF(plata‌​forma<>""*"",ROW(rut‌​_cliente)-ROW(BD_EV!‌​$A$3)+1),ROWS(BD_EV!‌​$A$2:A2))),""""),IFE‌​RROR(INDEX(rut_clien‌​te,SMALL(IF(platafor‌​ma=$B$1,ROW(rut_clie‌​nte)-ROW(BD_EV!$A$3)‌​+1),ROWS(BD_EV!$A$2:‌​A2))),""""))"
        cel = .Range("C3").FormulaArray

        arrayFormula = Replace(cel, "reemplazar", parte1)
        .Range("C3").FormulaArray = arrayFormula

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Kylo... loved your role at The Force Awakens. Should i dim the "arrayFormula"? if yes, should it be as string? thanks

Comment: Thanks, forget the fact that I got my butt whipped by a girl, yeah I did OK. And yes, make it it a `string`

Comment: Kylo, tried your first solution since i want to put the formula on cell, not value. it crashed on `.FormulaArray = arrayFormula` with 1004 error: cant assign formulaarray property of the range class.

Comment: could you show me the whole formula you want after the replace?

Comment: Sure thing! `"=IF(R1C2=""Todas"",IFERROR(INDEX(rut_cliente,SMALL(IF(plataforma<>""*"",ROW(rut_cliente)-ROW(BD_EV!R3C1)+1),ROWS(BD_EV!R2C1:R[-1]C[-2]))),""""),IFERROR(INDEX(rut_cliente,SMALL(IF(plataforma=R1C2,ROW(rut_cliente)-ROW(BD_EV!R3C1)+1),ROWS(BD_EV!R2C1:R[-1]C[-2]))),""""))"` Thats on VBA format. on A1 it is `"=IF($B$1=""Todas"",IFERROR(INDEX(rut_cliente,SMALL(IF(plataforma<>""*"",ROW(rut_cliente)-ROW(BD_EV!$A$3)+1),ROWS(BD_EV!$A$2:A2))),""""),IFERROR(INDEX(rut_cliente,SMALL(IF(plataforma=$B$1,ROW(rut_cliente)-ROW(BD_EV!$A$3)+1),ROWS(BD_EV!$A$2:A2))),""""))"`

Comment: I can't test your formula, but it looks like I left out a set `""` at the very end of the `parte1` variable formula. Try that and see if it works.